# Formatting Aggregate Sum Results to a certain number of decimals with MSACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following SQL Query in Access:

```
SELECT ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM, EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME, ROUND(Sum(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_HOURS),1) AS Sum_OfASSIGN_HOURS, ROUND(Sum(ASSIGNMENT.ASSIGN_CHARGE),2) AS SumOfASSIGN_CHARGE
FROM ASSIGNMENT, EMPLOYEE
WHERE (((ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM)=[EMPLOYEE].[EMP_NUM]))
GROUP BY ASSIGNMENT.EMP_NUM, EMPLOYEE.EMP_LNAME;
```

Which yields the following results:

[image: Sample Result]

However I cannot figure out how to format the ASSIGN_HOURS column (the far right column) into a two decimal set. I know that I can use the `Format` property when normally dealing with datatables but as this is being done in SQL, I cannot seem to use it here without an error popping up alerting me to such.

I am wondering, how can I format the result set using only SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Format` function in Access SQL.

```
SELECT ..., Format(Round(...), '0.00') ...
```

This is for T-SQL but AFAIK the usage is the same in MS-Access SQL.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Again, this is T-SQL too but it should be compatible with MS-Access SQL.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/12723